# Is it possible to create software Raid array with operating system partition included?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, raid, software-raid

I know that software raid array can be created in the OS it self. But my question is, Is it possible to create a software raid array including partition which is having Operating System installed ? Or Is there any limitation that operating system partition should not be included in the software raid array.

Comment: In Windows the boot (active) partition is separated from the main OS partition, so it's possible to what you asked.
I suppose there's a way to do the same thing with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux this is accomplished using an "initial RAM disk" which lives on a non-raid partition (typically /boot mounted on /dev/sda1) .  This initial RAM disk contains enough utilities to activate the RAIDs and LVs and switch over to the LVM/RAID main root filesystem.

The gentoo distribution has an article outlining how to do this for gentoo.

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Initramfs/HOWTO

Instructions for other distributions will vary, but the concepts are shared.